# Helix Sample ASPCore using Docker

Tags: helix, docker

I tried to run the Helix Sample for ASPCore using docker but I get an error that says

MsBuild timeout out while trying to get project to project references.
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; nuget restore -Verbosity quiet' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'solution' failed to build : Build failed

Has anyone encountered the same error?

Thanks

Comment: Disable your VPN client/corporate proxy.

Comment: is it building your solution from Visual Studio ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu Not building from Visual Studio but from the docker install